# Python selenium automation a tag does not contain a href, link only generates when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, selenium

I am trying to automatically test a website (**https://homely.com.au**). This site has list of names (as shown below) and if I click on each name it routes me to a different page where it stores that information, but the `<a>` tags does not contain any links.

I assume some JavaScript is running in the background.

[image: here]

As you can see, if I click on that `<a>` element with Selenium, it takes me to this page:

[image: here]

Here is what I managed to achieve with Selenium thus far:

```
#storing the url so after going to different url it needs to come back and click to the next element

    url = driver.current_url
    #Getting each agent element list
    for attr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@class="agent"]'):
        #visiting the page again to make list of persons visible again
        driver.get(url)
        #clicking on each of then hence visiting them
        attr.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="info"]/h1/a').click()
```

But as suspected, this code does not work if there is a way to get the link, or visit each link in the list of names?

Last but not least, here is the agent class `div`'s **HTML** (HTML of the agent in the picture):

```
<div class="agent">
    <div class="pic">
        <a>
            <img class="img-circle hoverZoomLink" src="//res-1.cloudinary.com/hd1n2hd4y/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,c_fill,w_150,h_150,g_face,dpr_1.0/user-default.jpg">
            </a>
            <label class="premier-label hide">
                <!-- react-text: 178 -->Premier 
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <span class="agent-text">Agent</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h1>
                <a>THE NAME OF THE PERSON GOES HERE</a>
            </h1>
            <p class="company">Vanguarde Estate Agents</p>
            <div class="Rating">
                <span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper">
                    <svg class="icon icon-star-outline-medium">
                        <use
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-star-outline-medium">
                        </use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper">
                    <svg class="icon icon-star-outline-medium">
                        <use
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-star-outline-medium">
                        </use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper">
                    <svg class="icon icon-star-outline-medium">
                        <use
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-star-outline-medium">
                        </use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper">
                    <svg class="icon icon-star-outline-medium">
                        <use
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-star-outline-medium">
                        </use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper">
                    <svg class="icon icon-star-outline-medium">
                        <use
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-star-outline-medium">
                        </use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span class="Rating-label">No reviews</span>
            </div>
            <p class="recommendation hide"></p>
            <!-- react-empty: 192 -->
        </div>
        <div class="total-listings-info">
            <p class="total-listings">
                <!-- react-text: 195 -->18
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 196 -->
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 197 -->sold
                <!-- /react-text -->
            </p>
            <p class="message">
                <!-- react-text: 199 -->in 
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 200 -->Sydney (CBD)
                <!-- /react-text -->
            </p>
            <p class="message">
                <!-- react-text: 202 -->past 
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 203 -->12
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 204 --> months
                <!-- /react-text -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="listings-value-info hide">
            <p class="value">$23.58m</p>
            <p class="message">listed sold value</p>
            <p class="message">on Homely</p>
        </div>
        <div class="office-bar hide" style="background: rgb(241, 241, 241);">
            <img src="//res-4.cloudinary.com/hd1n2hd4y/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,c_fill,h_30,dpr_1.0/v1430193584/franchiselogo-14883.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: As it stands, the question still is pretty hard for me to understand, w/o the obnoxious formatting out of the way. You just want to click and navigate to all the agents displayed right?

Comment: Yes but a tags does not contain any links so i have to click them

Comment: But when i click them the old page goes away (i visit the agent info page) and i have to go back to the old pags to make the agents visivle again

Comment: Should a new tab work better for opening each agent .. While the other page with agents stays there

Comment: OK, I see a solution, give me 30 mins to muster the code. I will write it in JavaScript/WebdriverIO, but you can easily extrapolate the method to your python bindings.

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: brother you busy  ?

Comment: yessir! I am terribly sorry for leaving you hanging. Had an emergency. I'll deliver once I'm at a laptop again. To sumarize my solutin: Just extract all the agents names from the InfiniteList and then check each URL individually. It's https//<baseURL>/agent/<agentname>.toLowerCase(). It's a workaround since this is a React app.

Comment: i did that .. haha the problem is not every link is equal to the https//<baseURL>/agent/<agentname>.toLowerCase() 5 out 20 are different

Comment: anything you can do with selenium ?

Comment: and no worries, you trying to help to some random guy on internet even with your busy schedule.. i appreciate it thanks again

Comment: Yes, this can easily be done with Selenium + a bit of extra code to manage the list of agents + navigation to each agent URL & asserting the content.

Comment: i was trying that with my code.. selenium's click() is the only since a tag does not contain any href page only opens when clicked, can you help me with this ? or at least point me to right direction ?